# Permutation (or Combination?) Word Problem

Tags: combinatorics

I'm continuing to work through permutations and combinations and my book has the following question:

> A box contains 9 red, 4 blue, and 6 yellow chips. In how many ways can
>   6 chips be chosen if: 
>   a) all 6 chips are red 
>   b) all 6 chips are yellow 
>   c) 2 chips are blue

I had no problem answering a) and b); however c) is stumping me. The answer, according to the text, is 8,190 however I can't figure out how they're arriving at that number.

I thought it would be:
$$(19\cdot 18\cdot 17\cdot 16/4!)/2! = \frac{19\cdot 18\cdot 17\cdot 16}{4!\cdot 2!}$$
but that returns $1938$, not $8,190$.

At this point in the text we've only covered the Permutation and Combination formulas: nPr and nCr.

Help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number of ways of choosing 2 blue out of 4 is $\binom{4}{2}.$  After that you have 4 chips remaining which can be chosen from either  9 red or 6 yellow or both. So you are choosing 4 chips from $9 + 6 =15$ chips.
Putting all together, you get $$\binom{4}{2}\binom{15}{4}.$$

Comment: Thanks so much for the textual explanation (not to mention the calculation)! Really helpful.

Comment: No problem. glad to help..:)

Comment: Sorry, one more question on this. After choosing 2 blue out of 4, why would the the 4 chips remaining not be chosen from 9 red, 6 yellow and/OR 2 blue? In other words after you choose the 2 blue chips aren't there still 2 other blue chips remaining that could be chosen to fill the remaining 4 places?

Comment: Never mind. Got it. The problem states only 2 chips are blue, so we don't include them. If the problem said "at least 2 chips are blue" then we'd include the remaining 2 blue chips in the second combination: 17C4, as opposed to 15C4.

Comment: Im glad you got it. If it however said at least 2 blue chips, then we could have 2 blue, 3 blue or 4 blue chips.So that will be (4C2*15C4)+(4C3*15C3)+(4C4*15C2)

Comment: Ahh, of course...Thank you so much! Just so I'm clear: if the problem said "4 chips are yellow", we'd take: 6C4 * 13C2. Correct?

Comment: Yes, Correct!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve those kind of questions using generating functions:
- For the choice of red chips: $1+x+...+x^9=\frac{1-x^{10}}{1-x}$ (which means you can choose no red chips or 1 or 2 and so on up to 9).
- For the blue chips: $x^2$ since you have to choose $2$ blue chips.
- For the yellow chips: $1+x+...+x^6=\frac{1-x^7}{1-x}$ (once again, you can choose up to 6 yellow chips).
Now, the generating function to your problem would be $f(x)=\frac{1-x^{10}}{1-x}x^2\frac{1-x^7}{1-x}$. What you need is the coefficient of $x^6$, which is the number of ways to choose exactly $6$ chips under the above restrictions.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You want 2 blue chips out of 6 and 4 non-blue chips out of 15.

So $_6C_2\cdot _{13}C_4 = 15\cdot \frac{15\cdot14\cdot13\cdot12}{4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1} = 15\cdot (15\cdot7\cdot13)= 20475$.